# Android 4 does not scale vector drawable

Tags: android, drawable, scaling, android-4.4-kitkat

I'm converting code back from Android 7 to Android 4.4

Specifically I'm trying to draw a custom Switch with a custom Track and Thumb. On Android 7 it works fine, on Android 4 the Thumb drawable is not scaled AT all, making it look very ugly.

[This is how it looks on Android 4, with an unscaled thumb drawable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdV4f.jpg)

[This is how it looks on Android 7, which is the intended look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sP52.jpg)

Since defining the track and thumb in an XML file crashes the app under Android 4, I do it in code as follows:

```
    Drawable drawable = VectorDrawableCompat.create(m_resources, switchId, getTheme());
    sw.setTrackDrawable(drawable);

    Drawable thumb = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.switch_thumb_small);
    sw.setThumbDrawable(thumb);
```

The file switch_thumb_small.xml contains a selector with 2 layers, with either: 
1. a black circle
2. a white cross inside
for the non-checked state
or: 
1. a black circle
2. a white checkmark inside

But the whole thumb drawable looks like a narrow egg, instead of a circle, as shown in the linked images.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

just add tools:targetApi="lollipop" in xml and set drawable using xml

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, but unfortunately it does not make a difference. The problem is not that it doesn't compile. In Android Studio everything looks fine. But when running on a Kitkat device, the thumb is scaled wrongly.

Comment: yes in KitKat devices thumb is auto-scaled so you should use custom git library . use this link https://github.com/RiccardoMoro/RMSwitch

Comment: this perfect library as you want you can design your switch.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to try out the library as a stand-alone project. But after integrating it into my project, I got errors when trying to inflate the layout. The fatal error was about unknown integer for the "@drawable/happy". 
Strangely enough (?) this was only at runtime. In Android Studio the switch renders fine.